# How does windows listen for system hotkeys?

Tags: windows, winapi

For a project I am working on. I was wondering, how does Windows 10 listen for system hotkeys? Is there some system service in the background doing it?

By system hotkeys I mean <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and similar.

Comment: How keyboard input works in Windows: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-keyboard-input-works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a key is pressed, the Windows kernel receives the message from the keyboard driver and adds it to a system message queue. These messages get sent to all the running programs on the machine, including the ones that handle hotkey presses.

Documentation on which programs handle which key combinations is sparse, but it's a safe bet that either Windows Explorer, "Windows Session Manager" or "Shell Infrastructure Host" applications that you may see in your task manager are responsible for handling these key combinations.

For example, the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> combination to open "Run" is handled by Windows Explorer. If you close Windows Explorer from task manager and then try to use that combination, it won't work. More low-level combinations like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> would likely be handled by the session manager or the shell infrastructure host.

So, there is no single program that handles all of the key combinations. It's a mix of several pre-installed Windows applications. Windows Explorer, for example, is responsible for the majority of the GUI on your PC and handles a good number of those key combinations.

Edit: Desktop Window Manager seems to be the one that handles key combinations like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand and also wm_command.

These keys are handled in the core windows UI dll, user32.dll.

This is from an editor's help explaining how a particular text editor is programmed.

**Structure of a Windows program**

Windows provides a large number of controls implemented as windows. This program uses the RichEdit window mimicing an Edit window (that notepad uses). This gives us Word like editing ability while still keeping it as text.

**Sub Main**

A program starts and registers the windows it will be using (RegisterWindowsEx). 
It then creates the windows and any child windows including inbuilt controls (CreateWindowEx).

It creates menus and accelarator keys.

It sets options for both the main window and the well over 100 options for the RichEdit window. It also tells the RichEdit window to notify the main window of certain messages that the RichEdit window gets.

It then shows the windows and updates them. Your program is now running as a graphical program.

Enters a loop and sends all messages received to DispatchMessage which sends it to either the main window procedure or the RichEdit window procedure. 
When the window closes your loop exits and the program ends.

**Window Procedure**

This is the heart of a windows program. This program has two, the main window and the RichEdit window.

The programmer has to write the main window procedure. Although one that just hooks up default plumbing is only three lines of code.

All windows have a default windows procedure. This handles borders, menus, titlebars, cursor, pointer, etc. In the case of RichEdit the window procedure offers most of the features of MS Word.

There are general windows messages (like window resizing wm_size) from the window manager to either window depending on message. Edit control notifications (RichEdit also sends the same notification messages as a Edit control) and RichEdit notifications are sent by the Richedit window to the main window.

We only handle messages that we need to. We let windows draw the windows' borders and so pass messages for us to do so to our default windows' procedure. We process messages like a menu item has been chosen when we get a WM_Command message.

The window manager sends mouse messages to the main window if the pointer is over a border, menu, or titlebar. If it is over the RichEdit then RichEdit window will get these messages, although you could ask RichEdit to forward them to you as this program does for text has changed and context menu.

Most keys go to the RichEdit control. It has an extensive keyboard editing interface. System keys (like Alt + F4) and menu keys (Alt + F) are sent to the main Window that typically doesn't process them but passes it to default window procedure. The main window waits for the default procedure to send it back as a command to execute (like WM_Close to exit or WM_Command for a menu item that was chosen).

Unless we register other keys they will go to RichEdit window. EG: Ctrl + A selects all text and is part of RichEdit keyboard interface (it then sends the main window a selection change message). However Ctrl + S is not part of RichEdit keyboard interface and RichEdit ignores it. So we need to register Ctrl + S, so the main window gets it instead of RichEdit, but not Ctrl + A.

In a function that is a Select Case the main window procedure checks if it will process the message. If it doesn't it will call the default window procedure that will process the message if necessary.

Then

To exit the program you close the window by sending it a WM_Close message. This will turn into a WM_Destroy message that you will receive and you call PostQuitMessage. Your window procedure is now over.

The main loop receives a WM_Quit message and exits the loop.

The last two lines destroys the accelerator table and context menu (as it isn't assigned to a window). Other menus that were assigned to the window are automatically destroyed. The program is over.